# How do you determine if a set is a domain?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am unsure of how to determine if a set is a domain.

According to the book, $\operatorname{Im} z>1$ is a domain but $\operatorname{Im} z=1$ is not a domain. How can you tell?

Comment: Start by reminding yourself what the definition of a domain is, and then carefully work out (or even try to draw) the two sets. "$Im(z)>1$" and "$Im(z)=1$" are not even sets. You probably mean $\{z\mid Im(z)>1\}$ and $\{z\mid Im(z)=1\}$ I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In analysis, a *domain* is a set which is *open* and *connected*.

- You can check if something is connected by, heuristically, seeing if it can be broken up into two disjoint pieces. Determining whether a set is connected algebraically is a little more complicated, but I assume that this is not what is being asked.
- You can check if something is open by seeing if, for every point $x$ in the set, there is a sufficiently small radius $r$ such that an open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$ can be completely contained in the set.

So in the example of $\mathrm{Im}(z) =1$, if you pick a point in this set, clearly no open ball around that point can be completely contained in the set. But in the case of $\mathrm{Im}(z) > 0$, you can, because even if the point is very close to the line $\mathrm{Im}(z) = 0$, it can't ever lie on the line, so there's always space to make a tiny ball around it.