# How can I know if a set is a complex domain

Tags: complex-analysis

I have already seen  [How do you determine if a set is a domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365700/how-do-you-determine-if-a-set-is-a-domain) this answer, but it was not really helpful since there were very simple examples.

In my textbook there are some sets given and I should tell which one of these is a domain. For example $$U_1:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid \vert z^2-3\vert<1\}$$ or $$U_2:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid \vert z^2-1\vert<3\}$$
Actually I know from the textbook solutions that $U_1$ is not a domain, but $U_2$ is one. But I have no idea how to tackle such problems expect of trying to draw the sets. For example $U_1$. I am looking for all $z$ with $z^2-3$ is inside the unit disk. What is equivalent to looking for all $z$ so that $z^2$ is inside the disk $D_1(3)$. But how am I suppose to imagine how the set of all these $z$ looks like. Obviously it is kinda easy to find some single points that are inside the set, but how am I supposed to determine if it's connected or not. The question of those sets are open or not is mostly very easy. But I see no way how to handle the connectedness. And what do I do with even more complicated sets like $$\{z\in\mathbb{D}\mid \vert \vert z\vert^2-2\vert<1\}$$ (what is a complex domain btw) or
$$\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid \vert z\vert<1 \text{ and } \vert z-2\vert>\sqrt{5} \}$$
(what is even a star domain). These are all exercises from my textbook, but there was nothing about how to acutally handle these problems. The chapter just introduced the definition of a domain and was mainly about the Cauchy Theorem.

Honestly I am not even able to draw these sets, so I would appreciate any help!

Comment: That first one you can see is not a domain by recognizing that it's not connected: it consists of $z$ near $\sqrt{3}$ and near $-\sqrt{3}$. If you increase the distance threshold past $2\sqrt{3}$, then those disks merge and it becomes a domain. You can think through your third example kind of the same way: to be in that set you need $|z|^2$ to be close enough to $2$, which means you're near the circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ which makes an annulus, which is connected.

Comment: That last one is a bit more tricky to see without some visual thinking...the point is basically that the shortest horizontal line in the set is going to be $(-1,2-\sqrt{5})$, so the whole domain is a kind of pac-man shape with a connection between the upper and lower parts through that segment.

Comment: That said although generally being reasonably comfortable with things like preimages is useful, this is kinda low priority as complex analysis topics are concerned.